# Android - Does onServiceDisconnected be called after Activity onStop?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a remote service, and I want to use the service to check some conditions in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. But sometimes I got "binder null" exception when I back from other activities. I set binder to null in `onServiceDisconnected`.

My question:

1. Does `onServiceDisconnected` be called after activity onStop?
2. Is it better to `bindService` in `onStart` instead of `onCreate`?
3. Could you please explain simply the difference of local service and the remote service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) No. `onServiceDisconnected()` only gets called when the Service terminates unexpectedly, like when the process hosting the Service crashes. It will not be called when you unbind from the Service yourself. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html#onServiceDisconnected%28android.content.ComponentName%29):

> Called when a connection to the Service has been lost. This typically
>   happens when the process hosting the service has crashed or been
>   killed. This does not remove the ServiceConnection itself -- this
>   binding to the service will remain active, and you will receive a call
>   to onServiceConnected(ComponentName, IBinder) when the Service is next
>   running.

2) Generally, if you don't need to be connected to the Service while your Activity is stopped, then yes, binding in `onStart()` and unbinding in `onStop()` is the right way to go. The idea here is that you won't be wasting resources when your Activity is in the background. However, the [documentation for bound services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) state that binding in `onCreate()` and unbinding in `onDestroy()` is OK too in some cases.

3) A local Service implies that the Service is in the same process as the consumer.  A remote service is a Service that is in a different process.